# PrintJobListener in java does not produce any output

Tags: java, printing

My code:

```
   PdfBook pdfBook = new PdfBook(decodePdf, printingDevice, attributeSet);
    SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(pdfBook, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, null);
    DocPrintJob printJob = printingDevice.createPrintJob();
    PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(printJob);
    try {
      printJob.print(doc, attributeSet);
      System.out.println(pjDone);
    } catch (PrintException e) {
        LogWriter.writeLog("Exception " + e + " printing");
    }

                        try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
    decodePdf.closePdfFile();  

    System.out.println("Exiting printing process");      
    return null;

}
class PrintJobWatcher {
// true iff it is safe to close the print job's input stream
boolean done = false;

PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
    // Add a listener to the print job
    job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
        public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            allDone();
        }
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            allDone();
        }
        public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            allDone();
        }
        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            allDone();
        }
        void allDone() {
            synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
                done = true;
                PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
            }
        }
    });
}
public synchronized void waitForDone() {
    try {
        while (!done) {
            wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

}

My question:
I wanted to determine how can I get any value if a print job failed or completed? I tried the code above but, it seems that I can't get any value from the PrintJobListener. My goal is to print a document on a specific printer. It will not return to the main function if the print job is still not finished. Some print job takes 2-3 minutes to be completed. However, even if the print job is not yet completed, it returns immediately to the main function. Are there any ways to get a value from the printJobLister during and after the printing operation?

I searched related questions about this but none of these questions produced the answer that I'm looking for.:(